# npm ERR! react-amplify-project-three@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts --max_old_space_size=2048 build`

Tags: node.js, npm, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

ERROR:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-amplify-project-three@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts --max_old_space_size=2048 build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-amplify-project-three@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-30T05_23_44_594Z-debug.log
```

Running this step in Bitbucket Pipeline:

```
  - step:
      name: Dev Docker Build
      deployment: dev-docker-build
      trigger: manual
      size: 2x
      script:
        - npm install
        - npm run build
```

Configuration used:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=2048 build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

What would be the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have answer for this . Add this line "CI=false" in your npm command

```
  - npm install
  - CI=false npm run build
```